# ¿Cómo cambiar el estado de las propiedades de un objeto que se encuentra dentro de un array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Qué tal, vengo desarrollando una aplicación en NextJS, el asunto es que tengo un formulario que envía información a una API para posteriormente ser cargado en Mongo; sin embargo, debido a que el modelo contiene un array de objetos se me está dificultando el poder manipular los campos que representan las propiedades de estos, estoy intentando usar una función que se encarga de manipular el estado por medio de la propiedad onChange pero aún así no me permite ingresar datos en los campos. Adjunto fragmentos de código para hacer más entendible el caso:

**Modelo**

```
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    productCode: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    material: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    season: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    color: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    sizes:[
        {
            size:{
                type: String
            },
            stock:  {
                type: Number
            },
            prize:{
                type: Number
            }
        },
        {
            size:{
                type: String
            },
            stock:  {
                type: Number
            },
            prize:{
                type: Number
            }
        }
    ]
    
})
```

**Hook de estado**

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({
productCode: formData.productCode,
category: formData.category,
name: formData.name,
material: formData.material,
season: formData.season,
color: formData.color,
sizes:[
  {
    size: formData.sizes[0].size,
    stock: formData.sizes[0].stock,
    prize: formData.sizes[0].prize
  },
  {
    size: formData.sizes[1].size,
    stock: formData.sizes[1].stock,
    prize: formData.sizes[1].prize
  }
]
```

});

**Componente**

```html
<p>
          Color:{" "}
          <input
            type="text"
            name="color"
            value={form.color}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </p>
        <div>
          <p>Talla S</p>
          <p>
            Talla:{" "}
            <input
              type="text"
              name="size"
              value={form.sizes[0].size}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </p>
          <p>
            Stock:{" "}
            <input
              type="number"
              name="stock"
              value={form.sizes[0].stock}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </p>
          <p>
            Precio:{" "}
            <input
              type="number"
              name="prize"
              value={form.sizes[0].prize}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </p>
    </div>
```

**Función handle**

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;
    setForm({
      ...form,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
```

Creo que el problema está en la función handle pero no estoy realmente seguro, muchas gracias.

Comment: Olvide mencionar, el problema ocurre unicamente con los campos que representan  las propiedades de cada objeto dentro de sizes. Con el resto de propiedades no tengo ningún problema, los inputs se ingresan correctamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes que estas tratando la propiedad `sizes` como un valor de tipo `string`, cuando es array de objeto.

La solución que te propongo es la de añadir un manejador para este tipo de campos utilizando el indice del array, te muestro un ejemplo:

- Manejador:

  ```
  const handerResize = (event, index)=>{
    const { sizes } = form
    const { value, name } = e.target;
    sizes[index][name] = value
    setForm({ ...form, sizes });
  }
  ```
- Componente de React

  ```
  <div>
    {form.sizes.map((size, index) => {
     return (<div>
       <p>{`Talla ${index === 0 ? 'S' : '¿¿¿???'}`}</p>
      <p>
        Talla:{" "}
        <input
          type="text"
          name="size"
          value={size.size}
          onChange={(event)=> handerResize(event, index)}
        />
      </p>
      <p>
        Stock:{" "}
        <input
          type="number"
          name="stock"
          value={size.stock}
          onChange={(event)=> handerResize(event, index)}
        />
      </p>
      <p>
        Precio:{" "}
        <input
          type="number"
          name="prize"
          value={size.prize}
          onChange={(event)=> handerResize(event, index)}
        />
      </p>
    </div>)})
  </div
  ```

Comment: Muchas gracias, solucionó al 100 mi problema :)